# How can i append files to one another in the order i want in linux using pipes or redirects?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, awk

Lets say i have different files in a folder that contains the same day data such as :

```
ThisFile_2012-10-01.txt
ThatFile_2012-10-01.txt
AnotherSilly_2012-10-01.txt
InnovativeFilesEH_2012-10-01.txt
```

How to i append them to each other in any preferred order? Would below be the exact way i need to type in my shellscript? The folder gets same files everyday but with different dates. Old dates disappear so every day there are these 4 files.

```
InnovativeFilesEH_*.txt >> ThatFile_*.txt
ThisFile_*.txt >> ThatFile_*.txt
AnotherSilly_*.txt >> ThatFile_*.txt
```

Comment: What do you mean by "any preferred order"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assumption:

- Want to preserve some specific ordering in which these files are appended.

Using the example you provided:

```
#!/bin/sh

# First find the actual files we want to operate on
# and save them into shell variables:

final_output_file="Desired_File_Name.txt"

that_file=$(find -name ThatFile_*.txt)
inno_file=$(find -name InnovativeFilesEH_*.txt)
this_file=$(find -name ThisFile_*.txt)
another_silly_file=$(find -name AnotherSilly_*.txt)

# Now append the 4 files to Desired_File_Name.txt in the specific order:

cat $that_file > $final_output_file
cat $inno_file >> $final_output_file
cat $this_file >> $final_output_file
cat $another_silly_file >> $final_output_file
```

Adjust the ordering in which you want the files to be appended by reordering / modifying the `cat` statements

Comment: Wait, what would be the name of the $that_file? Also will the other files disapear, and i would like to give new name to the final appended file.

Comment: See updated example. Name of `$that_file` is whatever `$(find -name ThatFile_*.txt)` finds (i.e. ThatFile_2012-10-01.txt for example). Now this is writing the 4 files in your example in a specific order into a new file called `Desired_File_Name.txt`

Comment: Im getting an error from ur script. It says find paths must usage: precede expression [-h] [-p] [path..] [expression]

Comment: I just tested the script on Ubuntu 11.x and it works fine. Which Linux/Unix system are you using? The error message is asking you to specify the search paths before the `-name file_name_*.txt` part. So `$(find ~/src/ -name file_name_*.txt)` where `~/src/` is an example path

Answer (score 2):

Finally, a use for "cat" as intended :-):

```
cat InnovativeFilesEH_*.txt ThisFile_*.txt AnotherSilly_*.txt >> ThatFile_*.txt
```

Comment: Of course, depending on whether `ThatFile_*.txt` glob-matches something that already exists or not, this may not have the desired effect. I would recommend removing the wildcard from the destination file, as well as use `>|` instead of `>>` (or just plain `>`, combined with appropriate noclobber settings if you need to protect against overwriting something valuable).

Comment: @twalberg: the OP said those 4 files are created every day and he's not trying to create ThatFile_*.txt from the contents of the other 3 files but instead append their contents to whatever's already in ThatFile_*.txt.